# Clean up [marker]/[markers] tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

Currently, 3 tags are used to refer to the Google Maps markers: [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker), [markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers) and [google-maps-markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-markers).

Obviously, [markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers) should be an synonym of [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker). However, the [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker) also has many other usages than the Google Maps API, for instance eclipse markers, openstreetmap markers, d3.js markers, etc. That means it can't simply get merged/synonymized into [google-maps-marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-marker).

I think the best option is to keep [marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker) and move all google maps related questions to [google-maps-markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-markers). Currently, that means these questions should be retagged:

- [google-maps-api-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3): [39](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers+google-maps-api-3) + [50](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-maps-api-3)
- [google-maps-android-api-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-android-api-2): [26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-maps-android-api-2) + [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers+google-maps-android-api-2)
- [google-maps-markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-markers): [9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers+google-maps-markers) + [14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-maps-markers)
- [google-maps-api-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2): [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-maps-api-2) + [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers+google-maps-api-2)
- [google-maps-sdk-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-sdk-ios): [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-maps-sdk-ios)
- [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api): [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markers+google-api) + [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/marker+google-api)

Assuming no questions had 2 of the above tags, this comes to a total of 158 questions.

As a little bonus [android-maps-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-maps-v2) should become a synonym of [google-maps-android-v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-android-v2).

Comment: Keep [tag:marker]? No, disambiguate [tag:marker]. Create tags (as needed), destroy that one.

Comment: @animuson that was my first approach. But then you get a lot of very specific, less used, tags. Is that prefered over a (maybe too) generic tag?

Comment: Yes. An ambiguous tag is an useless tag. But you should also consider whether a separate "marker" tag for each different program, etc is even valuable. For example, chances are that a question about "eclipse markers" could get away with *just* being tagged with eclipse. I doubt a separate "eclipse-markers" tag is necessary at all.

Comment: @animuson ok, that brings us to the next question: Is it actually usefull to have a tag for google maps markers? And if so, we still get a lot more: `openstreetmap-marker`, `openlayers-marker`, `leaflet-marker`, `d3.js-marker`

Comment: That would be a separate discussion, but from my minimal understanding there are several separate "Marker" classes within the Google Maps interface, which seems to indicate it's a large enough piece of pie to warrant its own tag. That's not my area to judge, though.

Comment: Okay, I'll investigate this a bit more, see whether a marker will be good and update the question with a new todo list.

Comment: @animuson – “An ambiguous tag is an useless tag.” … I am not sure about that. I frequently search for questions using a combination of “ambiguous” tags to get very specific answers. E.g., tags like `concurrency` or `multithreading` are, themselves, very ambiguous, but use them in conjunction with a particular programming language tag, and they become quite useful (e.g., “[concurrency] [c++]” vs “[concurrency] [swift]”). The same would seem to apply to a `marker` tag, IMHO.

Comment: @WouterJ – The `marker` and `markers` tags are still defined as synonyms for `google-maps-markers`. Given that other popular platforms have `Marker` types (I’d add Apple’s new [`Marker`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/marker/) to your list) defining it to be a synonym for Google’s seems inappropriate. I’d suggest not make `marker` a synonym for any particular platform’s implementation, and make `markers` a synonym for `marker`.